# Maven compile error: package weblogic.health does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, jmx

I'm trying to compile and run a maven project, and it has a `POM.xml` file. It has a few `.jar` files in its jar folder. And I simply import the whole project in Eclipse. I simply maven clean and then install. But it complains about the following errors. How can I fix it?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project WLStatusData: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mhossein/Documents/WLStatusData/src/main/DataCollector.java:[410,48] package weblogic.health does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mhossein/Documents/WLStatusData/src/main/DataCollector.java:[410,97] package weblogic.health does not exist
```

And here is my `POM.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mywork</groupId>
  <artifactId>WLStatusData</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WLStatusData</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jars.wlserver_10_3.server.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
    <version>11.1.1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.24</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.8</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml to analyze it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza updated it!

Comment: Looks like dependency of artifact wlfullclient is not public. Maybe you need to add a local/lan repository to obtain those references.

Comment: I in fact already had that jar file. I add it to my build path, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Closed as dup. In fact, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/1065197) explains how to solve your problem.

Comment: So what's the difference between adding a jar file and writing the dependency manually in POM?